# First data point in vector is not what i expected

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I wanted to create a vector using a for loop from a certain formula. My code shows the first point is zero, but when i calculate it by hand it should be different. Code provided

```
n<-12

x <- matrix(0, n+1, 1)
for (k in 1:n+1){
  x[k,] <- exp((2*(k-1)+1)/(2*n+2))
}
```

Calculating by hand:
`exp((2*0+1)/(2*n+2))` gives me a value of 1.039211

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
n<-12

x <- matrix(0, n+1, 1)
for (k in 1:(n+1)){
  x[k,] <- exp((2*(k-1)+1)/(2*n+2))
}
```

Output:

```
          [,1]
 [1,] 1.039211
 [2,] 1.122305
 [3,] 1.212043
 [4,] 1.308957
 [5,] 1.413620
 [6,] 1.526652
 [7,] 1.648721
 [8,] 1.780551
 [9,] 1.922922
[10,] 2.076677
[11,] 2.242726
[12,] 2.422053
[13,] 2.615718
```

The issue was that `1:n+1` is creating next sequence:

```
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

That is why you got first element as zero.